# Add a search box on a simple html page to search a site which doesn't use "?q=<search term>" in the search url

Tags: html, url, search-box

In order to avoid having to open multiple web sites when I search frequently used web search services, I've made a simple local web page with search boxes for these services, including Google and a few Norwegian dictionary web services. The HTML code below works fine for services which use the "?q=" syntax:

```
<form method="get" action="http://www.google.com/search" target="_blank">
<div style="border:0px dotted black;padding:8px;width:33em;">
<table border="0" cellpadding="2">
<tr><td>
<input type="text"   name="q" size="40"
maxlength="255" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="Google" /></td></tr>
</td></tr></table>
</div>
</form>

<form method="get" action="http://www.dinordbok.no/engelsk-norsk/" target="_blank">
<div style="border:0px solid black;padding:8px;width:33em;">
<table border="0" cellpadding="2">
<tr><td>
<input type="text"   name="q" size="40"
maxlength="255" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="Dinordbok (en-no)" /></td></tr>
</td></tr></table>
</div>
</form>
```

It also works fine when the site uses a different term than 'q':

```
<form method="get" action="https://ordbok.uib.no/perl/ordbok.cgi?" target="_blank">
<div style="border:0px solid black;padding:8px;width:33em;">
<table border="0" cellpadding="2">
<tr><td>
<input type="text"   name="OPP" size="40"
maxlength="255" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="Bokmål/nynorsk" /></td></tr>
</td></tr></table>
</div>
</form>
```

When I enter a search term in these two instances, a new web page pops up displaying the result correctly, just as if I'd entered the search directly from the site.

However, I wish to include a service which merely appends the search term directly to the url, like this: "*sitename*.com/*search term*". Case in point, looking up the word 'problem' on the https://www.naob.no/ordbok site results in the url https://www.naob.no/ordbok/problem.

What code should I use to make the resulting url conform to the site syntax?

Comment: you would probably have to post back to your own server and then create the url and redirect yourself or use js to build up a url and redirect to it

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but unfortunately, I'm quite new to html and javascript, and I have no idea how to implement it with a form. I'm looking into it and hope to find out how to use it :)